# Assigning all items to bins without optimal solution

Tags: python, or-tools

I am looking to put items in bins, where each item must come from a different category, each bin must hold a unique collection of items, and there are constraints on which items can be in the same bin. I don't know which type of problem this is. It seems similar to a multiple knapsack problem, but there is no "optimal" solution. There are potentially many equally valid solutions, or maybe only one, or possibly none.

More detailed description of the problem:

Consider I have 5 categories of items:
`["Fruit", "Vegetable", "Bread", "Meat", "Frozen"]`

There are 100 items in each category, where each item is not unique. For example, in Fruit there are 20 Apples, 50 Oranges, 10 Pears, 10 Grapes, 10 Bananas. In Bread there is 50 Bagels, 40 Loaves, 10 Baguettes. The other categories are similar in that the total number of items sums to 100, but there are duplicates of each item.

I am trying to place one item from each category into a bin. Each bin gets 1 each of Fruit, Vegetable, Bread, Meat, Frozen. There will be the same number of bins as there are items in each category. So for this example, 100 bins.

The constraints are:

- Each bin gets one item from each category of items
- Each bin must be unique. No bin can have the same combination of items as another bin
- Some items cannot be placed in the same bin. For example, Bagel cannot be in the same bin as Apple

I am not sure how to structure this problem. I am looking for some guidance on what class of problem this is, and what approach would be appropriate for solving it using OR-Tools.

Comment: I'm confused about what you want to do. I get that there is a list of categories, with fruit, vegetable, etc. but are the items in a separate list or dictionary? `categories = {"Fruit": {"Apples": 20, "Oranges": 50, "Pears": 10, "Grapes": 10, "Bananas": 10}}` Also, I don't get what you want in your final answer with the bins. What would be your final answer?

Comment: Did you try anything? Approaching problems like that ask for much more information as given (e.g. real-world data sizes) to prevent some "surprises". Semantically, getting something to work correctly without guaranteeing scalability looks not that hard though and i think we can expect some prep on your end: So... Take a boolean-variable matrix of size 500x100 (items, bins) and think about what kind of constraints you will need. Constraints 1 + 3 are trivial (cardinality=1 on column-parts + conflict between column-entries). Only constraint 2 hurts (a bit). Maybe you should omit those for now.

Comment: for constraint 2, let's if the numbers are small, you can create a signature for each bin,  them make sure they are all different.  Would be hard to scale though. In OR-Tools, the best solver would be CP-SAT.

Comment: The approach I have tried is to use random.shuffle on each category list, so ```["Apple","Apple","Pear","Grape" ...], ["Bagel","Baguette","Bagel","Loaf" ...]``` and then check each index of each category against the constraints (because the index is equivalent to a bin). If there are constraints that are violated, then it reshuffles the lists. It keeps going until all constraints are satisfied. The issue is for large sets, 10,000 entries, 20 or so constraints, it takes a very long time or may not solve.

Comment: I guess, i would tackle the uniqueness-constraint eagerly opposed to lazily (solving, checking, solving). Besides some potential problems with the chosen lazy-approach (the solver might not care about your reordering), i guess the solver should know about this and be in charge. Maybe it won't scale at all, but my first attempt would be a lex-sort on the signatures-bits (one hierarchy-lvl reification might needed) -> no quadratic blowup (compare all 2-combs) and also handles symmetry. On the bad side: the solver willl backtrack a lot i guess.

Answer (score 1):

The size of the problem that you describe here is not very large; with 5 categories and 5 items each you'll have only 5^5 = 3125 combinations of items.

If your real problem is also of this size, the easiest way to model it would be to make a table of all the allowed combinations:

| Id | Fruit | Bread | Vegetable | Meat | Frozen |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | `apple = 1` | `loaf = 1` | `carrot = 1` | `sausage = 1` | `icecream = 1` |
| 2 | `apple = 1` | `loaf = 1` | `carrot = 1` | `sausage = 1` | `brokolli = 2` |
| 3 | `apple = 1` | `loaf = 1` | `carrot = 1` | `sausage = 1` | `orangejuice = 3` |
| 4 | `apple = 1` | `loaf = 1` | `carrot = 1` | `chicken = 2` | `icecream = 1` |
| 5 | `apple = 1` | `loaf = 1` | `carrot = 1` | `chicken = 2` | `brokolli = 2` |
| 6 | `apple = 1` | `loaf = 1` | `carrot = 1` | `chicken = 2` | `orangejuice = 3` |
| 7 | `apple = 1` | `loaf = 1` | `carrot = 1` | `steak = 3` | `icecream = 1` |
| 8 | `apple = 1` | `loaf = 1` | `carrot = 1` | `steak = 3` | `brokolli = 2` |
| 9 | `apple = 1` | `loaf = 1` | `carrot = 1` | `steak = 3` | `orangejuice = 3` |
| 10 | `apple = 1` | `loaf = 1` | `carrot = 1` | `fish = 1` | `icecream = 1` |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |
| 3124 | `orange = 2` | `bagel = 2` | `carrot = 1` | `sausage = 1` | `brokolli = 1` |
| 3125 | `orange = 2` | `bagel = 2` | `carrot = 1` | `sausage = 1` | `orangejuice = 2` |

Only include lines in the table that are allowed, e.g. no line with apple and baguette together. Alternatively, you could also add constraints directly on the variables, but that is likely to have worse performance than filtering them out in advance.

Make 6 arrays of `IntVar` with one element for each bin. The first array is for the `Id` of the table (with `IntVar` domain from 1 to 3125) and one array for each category of groceries (`Fruit[]`, `Bread[]`, ..) with as many array elements as there are bins.

Use the `AddAllowedAssignments` constraint for each bin, i.e. make a vector `{Id[i], Fruit[i], Bread[i] ...}` for each bin and use the `AddAllowedAssignments` constraints to make sure the values of the groceries in the bin correspond to a line in the table.

Now add an `AllDifferent` constraint on the `Id[]` array to make sure each bin is a *different* line from the table.

Checking the limits on the number of specific items (20 Apples, 50 Oranges, etc.) will require some more variables. The most straightforward way to do this would be to define a `BoolVar` array for each type of item with an element for each bin, e.g. `AppleInBin[], OrangeInBin[], BagelInBin[], ...`, then add for each bin

```
    solver.Add(Fruit[i] == 1).OnlyEnforceIf(AppleInBin[i])        // 1 = apple
    solver.Add(Fruit[i] != 1).OnlyEnforceIf(AppleInBin[i].Not())
    solver.Add(Fruit[i] == 2).OnlyEnforceIf(OrangeInBin[i])        // 2 = orange
    solver.Add(Fruit[i] != 2).OnlyEnforceIf(OrangeInBin[i].Not())
    ...
    solver.Add(Bread[i] == 2).OnlyEnforceIf(BagelInBin[i])        // 2 = bagel
    solver.Add(Bread[i] != 2).OnlyEnforceIf(BagelInBin[i].Not())
    ... etc.
```

And finally add a constraint the sum of the items in bins is equal to the number of items of that type

```
    solver.Add(sum(AppleInBin[i] for i in range(nbins)) == 20)
    solver.Add(sum(OrangeInBin[i] for i in range(nbins)) == 50)
    ... etc.
```

This is just a sketch of the proposed solution, I haven't actually implemented / tested it so there are likely to be syntax errors in the code.